# react native styles

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Всем салют! пишу мобильное приложение на react native и у меня возник вопрос как можно стили поместить в 1 объект (StyleSheet.create(styles1,styles2))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> как можно стили поместить в 1 объект (StyleSheet.create(styles1,styles2))?

Например вот так

```
const obj = {
   stl1: StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
         height: 100
     }
   }),
   stl2: StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
         height: 200
     }
   })
}
// ...
<View style={obj.stl1.container}></View>
<View style={obj.stl2.container}></View>
```

Comment: не много не так, но вы мне дали идею, спасибо